# Proving a sequence of functions converges weakly*

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, weak-convergence

I am reading a book about functional analysis and I found the following example proving that some sequence converges weakly* but not weakly.

> Let $X=C[-1,1]$ be the space of continuous functions and 
>   $$\rho_n(t)=\left\{
> \begin{array}{ccl}
> n-n^2|t| &\text{if}& -\frac{1}{n} \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n} \\
> 0 &\text{otherwise}&
> \end{array}
> \right.$$
>   We consider the seequence functionals $f_n:X \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by 
>   $$f_n(\phi)=\int_{-1}^1\phi(t)\rho_n(t)\text{d}t, \qquad \phi\in C[-1,1].$$
>   We claim that $f_n$ weak^* converges to $f_0$ defined by $f_0(\phi)=\phi(0)$. Indeed,
>   \begin{equation*}
> \begin{split}
> |f_n(\phi)-f_0(\phi)|& =\left|\int_{-1}^1\phi(t)\rho_n(t)\text{d}t-\int_{-1}^1\phi(0)\rho_n(t)\text{d}t\right| \\
> & \leq \int_{-1}^1 |\phi(t)-\phi(0)|\rho_n(t)\text{d}t=\int_{-1/n}^{1/n} |\phi(t)-\phi(0)|\rho_n(t)\text{d}t \\
> & \leq \max\{|\phi(t)-\phi(0)| : -1/n\leq t \leq 1/n\}.
> \end{split}
> \end{equation*}

My question is: What happened in the last inequality? I know that given a Riemann-integrable function we have that 
$$\int_a^b f(x)\text{d}x\leq (b-a)\max\{|f(t)| : t\in[a,b]\}$$
but I do not know how to apply similar results here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $|\phi(t)-\phi(0)|$ is "pulled out" the integral sign and is majorized by the obvious $\max\{|\phi(t)-\phi(0)|: |t|\leq 1/n\}$, and you are left with the integral
$$\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}\rho_n(t)\,dt = 1$$

so that is what happened in the last inequality. (The first (or second) question you should have asked yourself is this: whatever happened to $\rho_n$?)

Comment: Then, if I have an integral of the form $\int_a^b f(t)g(t)\text{d}t$, I can always make it less or equal than $\max\{f|(t)|:t\in[a,b]\}\int_a^b g(t)\text{d}t$? In the affirmative case, can you prove that?

Comment: Yes, only In general you need to take the absolute value of $g$, (and you also need $|g|$ to be integrable!)  but in this case the function is non-negative.